# Combining Excel files using Power Automate and Excel Office Scripts

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

I need to work out a Power Automate flow to copy the data from 25+ Excel files into a master file.
The Excel files are reports that are received via email in the middle of night, and contain anywhere from 10 to 4,000 rows.

I have tried using an "Apply to Each" in Power Automate, but it takes hours for the flow to complete on just one worksheet, and is unmanageable given the overall volume.  I have also tried using Excel Office Scripts.  One script would retrieve the data and return it to Power Automate, and another Excel Script would write the data to the master file. Doing this, the data would retrieve in seconds just fine, but when it attempted to run the second Excel Script to write the data - it would say that it "aborted" or "timed out" - even though the script had run for less than 30 seconds. Despite trying multiple variations of the script, this was always the case.

A suggestion was made to try Graph API - and I found this video (https://youtu.be/mNwEk7hLdfE).  I was able to adapt my flow to just about all of it - I put together a new Excel Office Script that retrieves the data from the Excel file and returns it to Power Automate in JSON format. Following the flow in the video, when I get to the last step in this flow to "Send an HTTP request", I set the Body to be:

```
{
"values":Body('Run_Script')
}
```

The flow says that it succeeds but when I look at the Excel file no data has been added.  When I look at the raw input, I see that it is being passed in as:

```
"Body":"{\n\"values\":{\"result\":[{\"Col1\":\"Col1 Data\",\"Col2 \":\"Col2 Data\",etc}]\"]}\n}"
```

When I look at the raw output I see that it recognized the range and shows the correct column and row counts, numberFormats, etc -- but the "values" array is all blanks

```
("values":[["","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]])
```

I tried modifying the Body of the "Send an HTTP request" step to be:

```
{
"values":Outputs('Run_Script')?['body/result']
}
```

Doing this results in an error that "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."

When I look at the raw input, I see that it is being passed in as:

```
"Body":"{\n\"values\":[{\"Col1\":\"Col1 Data\",\"Col2 \":\"Col2 Data\",etc}]\n}"
```

I'm not sure what the error is?

I am open to trying different ways to do this - I just need it resolved as soon as I can.  If desired, I can share the Excel Scripts that I used to copy / append the data when it was timing out.

The last Excel script I tried to use to retrieve / append the rows are as follows:

Retrieve Data

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, wsName:string,headRows:number): WorksheetData[] {
    let worksheetInformation: WorksheetData[]=[];
    let ws=workbook.getWorksheet(wsName);
    let resize=headRows*-1;
    let values=ws.getUsedRange()?.getOffsetRange(headRows,0).getResizedRange(resize,0).getValues();
    worksheetInformation.push({data:values as string[][]});
    return worksheetInformation;
}

interface WorksheetData{
    data:string[][];
}
```

Append Data

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, wsName:string, worksheetInformation: WorksheetData[]) {
    let ws=workbook.getWorksheet(wsName);
    worksheetInformation.forEach((value) => {
        let last=ws.getUsedRange().getLastRow().getRowIndex();
        let range=ws.getRangeByIndexes(last + 1,0,value.data.length,value.data[0].length);
        range.setValues(value.data);
    });
}

interface WorksheetData{
    data: string[][];
}
```

When I run this with Power Automate the retrieve works perfectly - returns even up to 4k rows in a few seconds.  When it gets to the "Append" script, though, it says it "aborts" or "timesout" even though the entire flow ran for less than 1 minute.

Timeout message: "message": "We were unable to run the script. Please try again.\nOffice JS error: Line 7: Range setValues: Timeout\r\nclientRequestId: ef2a06ce-4c98-40f5-b69c-20bfa2777422",
"l

That particular time the entire flow duration was 0:55, and the particular step that said it timed out was 0:34. I had read that adjusting the "Retry Policy" may help, so I set it to Count: 90, Interval: PT30S.  Still did not fix it.

The worksheets themselves are fairly straightforward.  I sheet with a table on it.  15 columns of data such as Course Name, First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, Enrolled Date, Completed Date, Due Date, Score, etc (though that could change as reporting needs change, so don't really want the columns locked in).  Some of the reports have as few as 10 rows while others have up to 4,000 rows.

Comment: I think the video is helpful for you.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_14U7zjRw1o

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is one of the videos I had tried where I get a "Timeout" or "aborted" error whenever I try to do a larger spreadsheet, so unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: perhaps you could give another try with your original approach but this time on dopes using a higher degree of parallelism https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Degree-of-Parallelism-in-Power-Automate/ba-p/430847

Comment: If you can share the script, it would be handy, I’m sure we can make this work for you. Also, a sample of what each worksheet looks like (I’m assuming they’re all the same structure) would be handy as well.

Comment: @mmikesy90 - I had tried that but it still took way too long. Between all the sheets there are roughly 50k rows total

Comment: Added some additional info @skin

Comment: I was about to try and help but my Office Scripts instance has shat itself.  Big fat error from Microsoft.